# Cannot specify metadata relationship field when inserting custom metadata type records via API

Tags: metadata-api, custom-metadata

I have two Custom Metadata Types. Content__c and Section__c. Each Section has a required Content__c record.

I can insert Content__c records using a class generated from the metadata WSDL and everything works fine.

When I try to insert Section records and specify the Content__c field and give it the value of the developer name field, it throws this error:

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Unknown SObject Namespace for Metadata Error Id: 1304496764-90552 (-768177128) faultcode=soapenv:Server faultactor=

I have created a Section__c record using the Salesforce UI and linked it to a Content__c record. I then executed a readMetadata command via the API and was returned what I expected. The particular value of the metadata relationship looks like this:

```
CustomMetadataValue:[apex_schema_type_info=(...soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), field=MB096__Content__c, field_order_type_info=(field, value), field_type_info=(field, ...soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), value=MB096__Test, value_type_info=(value, ...soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, true)]
```

(Note I put ... in place of the https:// because I can't post more than 2 links).

Here is the code I am using to test this out:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

MetadataService.CustomMetadata customMetadata = new MetadataService.CustomMetadata();
customMetadata.fullName = 'MB096__Section.Test';
customMetadata.label = 'My_Test';

MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue testValue = new MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue();
testValue.field = 'MB096__Has_Resource__c';
testValue.value = 'true';
MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue value2 = new MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue();
value2.field = 'MB096__Content__c';
value2.value = 'MB096__Test';
customMetadata.values = new MetadataService.CustomMetadataValue[] {
    testValue, value2
};
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
    service.createMetadata(
        new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customMetadata });
MetadataService.handleSaveResults(results[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed across all instances.

Comment: This issue seems to have returned - case 15971148

Comment: And now it is fixed again.